# javascript if something has css attribute of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, attributes

I would like to execute an animation when the page loads but only when a css attribute has a value of something. The animation works fine without the if statement. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("h1").css('font-size') == '36px'){

        $("h1").animate({
          "font-size" : "20px"
        }, 750);

    }

});
```

Comment: If you add `console.log($("h1").css('font-size'));` what does it show?

Comment: how many `h1` elements are in the page

Comment: when you know that it is not working because of "if statement" then your first think should go towards checking why it is not working and do console.log check as mentioned in above comment.

Comment: It shows 51px @j08691

Comment: @user2812034 well, then there you go... you know why the condition is not meant. Do you not know why the font-size is 51px?

Comment: @Gray no because in the css sheet I specified it as 36px

Comment: You should learn about your browser's DOM inspector. For example, in Chrome, you can right click on the `h1` and click "Inspect Element". You will see the developer tools on the bottom, and on the right you can see the styles that are applies to the `h1`. It could be that there is a more specific css rule being applied, or some !important flag somewhere.

Comment: @Gray yes I see where its getting the 51 from now. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Glad you could find it.

Comment: Is the h1 element not assumed to have a static font-size of 39px? Otherwise just use jquery selectors.

Comment: @user2812034 I have posted the method you used to determine why your function didn't work as an answer. Take a look and feel free to suggest an edit if there was something I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments from the OP, it would appear that a stray rule in a stylesheet has caused the font-size to be set to something other than they expected.

The way to determine this can be easily done with your browser's DOM inspector.
Generally, you can right click an element, hit inspect (or something like it) and see where the value is being set.

Here are some more specific how-to's for using these:

Chrome - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Inspector/Introduction_to_DOM_Inspector

Internet Explorer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to animate the `h1` elements which have font-size : 36px. Then you need to filter those elements before doing the animation as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("h1").filter(function () {
        return ($(this).css('font-size') == "36px");
    }).animate({
        "font-size": "20px"
    }, 750);
});
```

Comment: Note: `element.style[property]` will only include inline styles while `$(element).css(property)` will retrieve computed styles included those inherited from a stylesheet.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski updated.. (keep your comment for future references please)

Comment: I don't feel like this addresses the user's question. This is an alternate solution, but it doesn't explain why the condition is false.  If this works, then shouldn't the OP's solution work too?

Comment: @Gray Not exactly. This will test the `font-size` of each individual `<h1>` while the snippet in the question only tests the 1st `<h1>` -- `.css(property)` can only return the value for 1 element. If actually none of them are `36px`, then no this won't animate any of them either. But, that's information the OP hasn't given us.

Comment: Right, I understand that. You hit on what I was getting at. The issue (if you see his comment on the OP) is that the font-size is in-fact not 36px. If it were, then his solution would probably work... see this: http://jsfiddle.net/V7XtC/2/

Comment: @Gray I agree with Jonathan.. I am 99% sure that `$('h1')` is not addressing the OP's `h1` element. but let just wait for OP.

Comment: @Gray Sure. But, there is also the possibility that the 1st `<h1>` has different styling than the rest. http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/ekgWc/

Comment: @Mr_Green I have posted an answer that I think was used to solve the OP's question. I still think your answer is helpful - and a more robust method of doing what he is after, but I still stand by what I said about it not being the actual answer to the question... He should probably still implement it though!

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $('h1').eq(0).css('<property>') ) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to what he wrote? `.css()` returns the value of the property from the first element in the collection. He probably needs a value other than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

remove the 'px' from the code when equating the font size:

```
if($("h1").css('font-size') == '36'){

        $("h1").animate({
          "font-size" : "20px"
        }, 750);
```